# How to locate index.html / index.php in cPanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I am editing a wordpress website. My client had a team working on editing it and they simply used the Wordpress editor to make changes. When I log in to cPanel, I see a 'coming soon' page in the index.html file. But the changes that the design team made cannot be located in any file. Also, when I access the website with a http, it shows the website (even when it's not supposed to be launched) and when I access the website with a https, it shows the welcome page. I don't know how two different pages are displayed by just changing the transfer protocol. How do I edit the theme?

Comment: If you have uploaded the new index file. Try doing a hard refresh or open from different browser. It might be picking up data from stored cache.

Comment: clear your browser cache first and try accessing the page, if the situation remains the same, then check you need to update the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

If it is a WordPress website, the index file should be under this directory:
/website-root/wp-content/themes/ <- then the theme folder.

The theme, that's active on your website should be mentioned under Appearance > Themes. If you're not sure which one it is in /themes directory, look for the title here.

Answer (score 0):

As you have cPanel, you should have an access to .HTACCESS file for your account. You can set index/default page for your website from .HTACCESS file. Please add the following code:

DirectoryIndex MyFileName.html  // Replace MyFileName.html with your actual index file name.

HTTP and HTTPS should show the same contents. Please clear browser cache or verify your website from any alternate system or server.